# How to set condition to KMS key using CDK(typescript)?

Tags: typescript, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, amazon-kms

#### Env

CDK version - `"@aws-cdk/assert": "1.56.0"`

#### Description:

Using typescript and CDK -> create cloudformation template for "Stack". Command which is used for generating templates `cdk synth`

In a Stack: should be a condinion which should disable or enable granting `grantEncryptDecrypt` to some lambda.

#### Goal:

- Do not use `kms.Key` if condition is `true`.
- use typescript for generation cloudformation template

#### Part of CDK typescript code:

```
import * as kms from '@aws-cdk/aws-kms';

...
const keyCondition=new cdk.CfnCondition(this, 'ConditionName', {
    expression: cdk.Fn.conditionEquals('value', 'value')
});

// Import KMS key from stack's output
const encryptionKey = kms.Key.fromKeyArn(this, 'keyName', Fn.importValue('output_value'));
encryptionKey.grantEncryptDecrypt(this.mylambda);

const encryptionKeyCfg = encryptionKey.node.defaultChild as kms.CfnKey;
// But encryptionKeyCfg is undefined
encryptionKeyCfg.cfnOptions.condition = keyCondition;
```

#### Issue:

`const encryptionKeyCfg = encryptionKey.node.defaultChild as kms.CfnKey;` returns `undefined`
But e.g. same code with `EventSourceMapping` works well:

```
const child = myEventSourceMapping.node.defaultChild as lambda.CfnEventSourceMapping;
child.cfnOptions.condition = keyCondition;
```

#### Quesions:

1. How to set condition on `kms.Key` or `kms.CfnKey`(or which class should be used)?
2. Maybe different approach should be used in such sace?